# Giving the CPU a rest after rendering scene

Tags: c++, opengl, render, cpu-usage

I have read that it is a good idea to give a 3D program where rendering is involved a rest between rendering. Is this true? Will this reduce CPU load or is that unrelated?

If so, what method do you recommend? Also, does this have anything to do with framerate cap, i.e. cap at 60 fps and if it is not time to render another frame, rest and wait until we need to render another to meet the 60fps mark.

I am using OpenGL and C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple scenes, this can be a good idea. Otherwise, you're rendering a scene at 2000 fps, and you really won't ever get faster than 120 Hz or 60 Hz to the screen so those scenes are wasted. This lower CPU utilization is good when you have other apps you want to run. If you're running a game that is designed to be the only thing going, then run it at [full-bore](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/full-bore) without such throttling.

Comment: I disagree.  Even if it's the only thing running, that draws a lot of power, which kills batteries and power bills.

Comment: UX advice: don't design software to be only thing going. On a PC (including Mac) users expect multitasking environment, waiting for more than 10 seconds to Alt+Tab out or back to a application is very rude in such environment. Smartphone and tablet users also expect multitasking. Gaming consoles are perhaps exception but I have to few experience with them to jugde.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, limiting the framerate reduce the CPU load.

Also, if you have a 2000 fps your monitor won't show every frame, usually only 60fps.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate

I recommend the following method (code using boost date time and thread library):

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

long desiredFps=60;

void drawLoop() {
    using namespace boost;
    using namespace boost::posix_time;

    ptime lastDraw = microsec_clock::universal_time();
    while( true ) {
        ptime now = microsec_clock::universal_time();
        long diff = (now-lastDraw).total_microseconds();
        long desiredDiff = 1000000/desiredFps;
        if( diff < desiredDiff ) {
            this_thread::sleep(microseconds(desiredDiff-diff));
        }
        draw();
        lastDraw = now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sucha a waiting loop is not necessary if the driver is correctly configured to perform a V-Sync and the program doesn't disable it. Then SwapBuffers will block until the frame has been sent to the display. If your program is multithreaded, another thread will receive CPU time, and I strongly suggest you use it for things like I/O, user input processing, simulation, etc.

Comment: There is no waiting loop, it is a thread sleep, so another thread will receive the CPU and threat the input. Also, I recommend this method when you want to limit the FPS without using V-Sync. Let's say you want your FPS a bit above the monitor refresh rate, or you want it even slower than the monitor refresh rate.

Comment: Normally you want your frame rate to be exactly the monitor refresh rate. Otherwise you either get a beat (with V-Sync) or tearing artifacts. I mistook it for a wait loop due to the while statement. You normally don't have a "drawLoop" in a realtime graphics program. You have a event loop, that calls the drawing function at a steady pace.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard that waiting for the CPU to rest helps rendering performance. However, the same effect should already be happening. OpenGL should be resting the cpu between frame updates so this shouldn't be a concern in theory. Perhaps the "cpu resting" idea came from frameworks that do not execute the event loop per frame. I'll be looking at this thread if there's different perspective on this.

Comment: OpenGL on it's own doesn't direct application flow. If there is no waiting mechanism "outside" OpenGL application can spam redraw calls (glClear, ..., glSwapBuffers) as often as any other instruction. OpenGL may shield GPU from such spam but it has no power over CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I had a Gateway computer that was fine until I started to do graphics rendering.  The CPU became toast shortly after.

But that was a flaw in the computer, you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

In systems with shared(unified) GPU memory, such as low-end PCs and most smartphones, CPU and GPU compete with each other for memory bandwidth. Doing additional calculations that involve lots of memory accesses will interfere with texture reads and framebuffer updates resulting in lower framerate.

Answer (score 0):

Game engines should be multithreaded, and each thread working on a different frame buffer object, enabling double/triple buffering method ( it's mandatory ). Calls to glFinish ( ) won't yield a thread but a call to `(glX)SwapBuffers ()` will do when there is no more available buffer for drawing operation, automaticaly decreasing the cpu usage to an optimal point. Nearly every GL implementations are tuned to do that.